# Firefox/Chrome not working with Generic / Text Only printer.

Tags: windows-7, firefox, google-chrome, printing

I have a web page with some basic text:

```
< 





 875 000 096 099 
 DR DOCTOR ASSOCIATES 
 MILWAUKEE, WI 
 >
```

And I would like this text printed from a browser to a printer using the Generic / Text Only driver.  Internet Explorer versions 9 and up will print this text just fine.  However, Chrome will not print at all, and Firefox will print the text incorrectly.  It seems whenever there is a space in the text, Firefox will add a line feed and tab which looks like this:

```
< 





 875 
    000 
      096 
        099
 >
```

Whats annoying is that I can print from an app like notepad or excel just fine.  Any suggestions?

Comment: Two potential work-arounds if nothing else works: 1)Print from a screen capture utility or paste into an editor and print from there. 2)At least in Firefox, there is an add-in available called Print Edit (https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/print-edit/).  You delete what you don't want from the page and print, which seems to avoid those kinds of odd formatting.

Answer (score 1):

I finally found out what was causing the problem.  Printers connected with the Generic / Text Only driver can be very picky about what types of fonts you use.  The text would only print correctly if I used a fixed width font type.  Hopefully this will help anybody out there having similar problems.